# Is there a better way to find all the contiguous substrings of a string that appear in a given dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, substring

Is there a more efficient algorithm to find all the substrings that are part of a given language over alphabet than the following:

```
import string.ascii_lowercase as alphabet
languge = {'aa', 'bc', 'wxyz', 'uz'};
for i in xrange(len(alphabet)):
    for j in xrange(i,len(alphabet)):
        substirng = alphabet[i:j+1]
        if substirng in languge:
            print substirng
```

Comment: Tip: `import string.ascii_lowercase as alphabet`

Comment: Looks very efficient to me, just 351 checks. Why are you asking?

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do N-grams help in here?

Comment: @StefanPochmann what if we have very big dict?

Comment: @0x90 Doesn't matter, it's still 351 checks averaging O(1).

Comment: @0x90 . . . I take that back.  It would only be an issue in a memory-limited environment, to reduce the size of the dictionary.  If the dictionary fits in memory, then the looks will be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) or [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithms intended for this purpose:

> It is a kind of dictionary-matching algorithm that locates elements of
>   a finite set of strings (the "dictionary") within an input text. It
>   matches all strings simultaneously

There are numerous Python implementations for these algorithms.

Complexity for Aho-Corasick searching is `O(TextLength + AnswerLength)`, preprocessing O(n*σ), where n is overall length of all words in the dictionary, σ is alphabet size

For Rabin-Karp average time is `O(TextLength + AnswerLength)` too, but the worst time is  `O(TextLength * AnswerLength)`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly. You have an alphabet, or string. In this case a string of 26 characters, a-z. You wish to check if any of the strings given to you are substrings of the aforementioned "alphabet string".

If this is indeed the case, there is a better way.

Your current approach amounts to computing all possible substrings from the alphabet, which is O(N^2) in the general case of an alphabet of size N and 26^2 in your particular case and then checking if the substring belongs to your predefined set. A much better approach would be to simply loop over your given strings and [check if they are substrings of your alphabet](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-strings-find-first-string-subsequence-second/). This is an O(N) operation for each string in your predefined set. This brings the complexity down to O(NM).

This is better if M is noticeably smaller than N.

There might be even better ways, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

It is nicer if you use
`from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet` instead

```
language = {'aa', 'bc', 'wxyz', 'uz'}

for item in language:
    if item in alphabet:
        print item
```

this works but a list comprehension is preferred

```
substrings = [item for item in language if item in alphabet]
```

Comment: Also, your `language in alphabet` is wrong. And the whole thing is less efficient than the original (for "very big dict", which the OP mentioned in a comment).